# Open a new HTML page in a JS function and then write some HTML on it

Tags: javascript, html

I have this *main.html* file which has a button of type "button". It has a *create()* function that processes the *onclick* event.

I also have another page *test.html* which is in the same folder as the *main.html*.

What I want:

1. as soon as I click the button, *test.html* opens
2. create() write some html on it, like "Hello World"

I don't understand how to do it. I read about window.open() but I guess this is just a pop up, and I want a full-fledged page.

Comment: Concept is flawed...javascript on first page is gone when new page loads. Need more details of use case to sort out best approach. Using dynamic server side language to generate the html is one simple way

Comment: Please add more details and the code you have that attempts to do this so we can potentially help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function create()
{
    window.location = 'test.html';
}
```

This is your starting point. Then, you need to add some PHP or JS to your test.html file.

## Method 1: PHP

For example, you can get a message from the URL, that you're going to write.

Main file:
    function create()
    {
        window.location = 'test.php?p=Hello%World';
    }
Test file:

## Method 2: JS

You can also write a JS function in your test file, which is called as soon as the page is loaded.

Main file:

```html
function create() // Create function on 1st page
{
  window.location = 'test.html';
}
```

Test file:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function message()
    {
      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Hello world';
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="message();">
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I want, however, I want to type a string that is created in the create function. I guess it's my bad that I didn't specify it in the initial question. And also, the create function should be in the main.html file.

Comment: The create function is actually in the main.html file. However, do you want your string to be typed in an html input, or simply declared in the create function ?

Answer (score 3):

In the main.html:

```html
<input type='button' onclick='location.href=test.html' value='click me'>
```

in test.html

```js
function create() {
  // Write something in the page
}
```

```html
<body onload='create()'>
  
</body>
```